# How to set a filter in SQL that is based on a field but set at a future date?

Tags: sql, date, filter, databricks-sql

I am trying filter based on a date range that should only go to 2023-01-01 (or first day of the next year) that corresponds to a field and it's date range (current and previous dates).

My current filter in the where statement includes this but unsure how to set the first of the next year.

```
select * from df
where year(split_start_date) = year(dateadd(year,+1,current_date()))
```

I am able to filter based on year out of 'split_start_date' but want to set a cutoff to the first day of the next year.

Comment: Your query is not SARGable btw. Also, you don't need to do `year(split_start_date)` (which is what ruins SARGability).

Comment: What do you mean by "set a field", btw? `SELECT` queries don't edit any data...

Comment: Basically I want to only filter date ranges that correspond to split_start_date up to 2023-01-01 if that makes sense?

Comment: You essentially want `WHERE date <= '2023-01-01'`. You can dynamically create that date (if it's always going to be the first date of the first month) like `WHERE date <= CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)+1, "-01-01")`. Or if you have separate `year`, `month`, and `day` fields: `WHERE year <= CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)+1) AND month = 1 AND day = 1`.